# How to display arraylist<items> as a drop down in Java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Developing a simple java GUI application using swing.

I have a ArrayList fetched from a file. How do I display that as a drop down for the user to select. And how to obtain the object which the user has selected.??

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This link should help you to create the drop down menu: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Usingdropdownlists.htm

In the part where you insert items in your menu just loop throught your ArrayList items and select them one by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //insert in menu .. list.get(i); 
}
```

The actionlistener will take care of the action. ie to know wich element was selected.

Some more info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 2):

This is an example for using a fixed string array. It is a fairly simple extrapolation from this code to an arrayList imported from a file:

```
// define items in a String array:
    String[] languages = new String[] {"English", "French", "Spanish", "Japanese", "Chinese"};

    // create a combo box with the fixed array:
    JComboBox<String> comboLanguage = new JComboBox<String>(languages);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at `JComboBox`'s [constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). You can supply a `ComboBoxModel`, an array, or a `Vector`. If you have a `List` then just create a new `Vector` from it.

```
new JComboBox(new Vector(list));
```

If you want your combobox to dynamically change then you'll need to use a `ComboBoxModel`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of objects and want to display a value, you can use the Vector class as the model and then create a custom renderer using the  BasicComboBoxRenderer class to display the text.

```
    Vector<Employee> data = new Vector<Employee>();
    data.addElement(new Employee(1001, "John Smith"));
    data.addElement(new Employee(1002, "Linda Baker"));
    data.addElement(new Employee(1003, "Youcef Hussain"));
    data.addElement(new Employee(1004, "Jia Lia"));

    JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(data);
    jcb.setRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());

class ComboBoxRenderer extends javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer
{
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        Employee emp = (Employee)value;
        setText(emp.getName());
        return this;
    }
}

class Employee{
    protected int employee_id;
    public String employee_name;

    public Employee(int id, String name){
        this.employee_id = id;
        this.employee_name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.employee_name;
    }
}
```

Full code sample can be found here http://www.hostprojects.net/snippets/java/158/basiccomboboxrenderer-example